# Forces acting on a body in equilibrium

Tags: continuum-mechanics, equilibrium

The resultant force acting on a body in equilibrium is 0:

$$\iiint_R \rho {\bf b}\ dV + \iint_S {\bf t}^{(n)} ds = 0,$$

in which $R$ is a region inside the body,  $\rho {\bf b}$ the body force per unit volume, $S$ the surface of the region and ${\bf t}^{(n)}$  the surface traction.

I am not quite sure what to make of all these parts... for example, let $R$ be a solid cube made from uniform material, resting on a table. In this case $S$ consists of the 6 faces of the cube, and $\rho$ is its (constant) density.

But what are ${\bf t}^{(n)}$ and $\bf b$?

It seems ${\bf t}^{(n)}$ should point upwards (against gravity) on every point on the bottom face of the cube, and be 0 on the other five faces. Also, I think $\bf b$ is the gravitational acceleration $g$... is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vector ${\bf t}^{(n)}$ is the surface traction vector, and represents the force experienced by the surface of the blob of material in question. The vector ${\bf b}$ (I'm not sure if the extra $\rho$ in your formula is a convention matter) represents the body force experienced by each little piece of material in the inside of the blob.

The statement $\iiint_V {\bf b} dV+\iint_S{\bf t}^{(n)}ds=0$ is simply a more complicated version of the high-school physics formula $\sum F=0$ for an object which is at equilibrium (there is no net force, so there is no acceleration). In this more complicated case, we add together all the forces at each point in the interior and at the surface.

I believe the formula you gave is only the equilibrium condition for an object whose *center of mass* experiences no acceleration. Your formula can still hold for an object experiencing angular rotational acceleration. As an example, a uniform cube experiencing no body force but experiencing a traction force on 2 opposite faces that tries to rotate the cube will still satisfy the above equality, but the cube will attempt to rotate. However, the center of mass will

The vector ${\bf t}^{(n)}$ is often related to the local surface orientation through the Cauchy stress tensor,${\bf t}^{(n)}={\bf n}\cdot{\bf \sigma}$ where ${\bf n}$ is the surface normal, but that's another story. Is there anything which isn't clear, or which I haven't resolved?

Also, you're right in thinking that ${\bf b}$ is often given by the gravitational force ${\bf g}\rho$, although occasionally there can be more complicated forces at play, such as the body forces experienced by a charged solid object moving in a magnetic field, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

This is the general equation for momentum balance under steady state conditions. The first term is something called body force. It can be gravity or something else which acts on the body as a whole. The second term is called surface force. It is in general a tensor (say for example a stress tensor in case of fluid mechanics). Unlike body force, this acts only on the surface of the body. Shear stress is a classic example of such a force. If you could give under what circumstance are you reading this, it will be helpful. **t$^{(n)}$** is a tensor in general and a dot product is taken with the surface normal (which points away from the surface) to get the surface force.

Side notes:
This is the starting point for many famous equations (for example Navier stokes equation, although formalism is little different). The second term can be written in volumetric terms using Gauss divergence theorem.